# MSB4030 "Debug" is an invalid value

Tags: visual-studio-2013

[image]

FYI, I am using a MCVS 2013 to build and run my program. However, I kept getting the error as shown in the picture, I have try to google the solution out, but there are no much information available. Besides that, I also getting 127 warnings. Some one from here please tell me how to prevent this error happen. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the properties page for your project, under the Linker -> Debugging tab, you need to use true or false instead of `Debug` as shown in the figure I attached. [image: project property setting page]